CouchDB update one field of all documents
I'm working with CouchDB and Mango queries and I have a JSON structure for my documents with fields like "nome" (name) and "age". I want to modify all documents in my database by appending " Updated" to the end of the "nome" field. So, for example, if the name is "Pessoa 1", I want to update it to "Pessoa 1 Updated". How can I achieve this in CouchDB? I'm doing it using python btw.
I tried using Project Fauxton before going to python, tryed mango queries like:
{
   "selector": {},
   "update": {
      "$set": {
         "nome": "Test"
      }
   },
   "merge": true
}

But this just gives me invalid_boolean error.
